# Elasticsearch arrays query/filter

Tags: arrays, filter, elasticsearch

I'm looking at Elasticsearch for the first time and spent around a day looking at it. We already use Lucene extensively and want to start using ES instead. I'm looking at alternative data structures to what we currently have.

If I run *match_all* query this is what I get at the moment. I am happy with this structure.

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 22,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "integration-test-static",
            "_type": "sport",
            "_id": "4d38e07b-f3d3-4af2-9221-60450b18264a",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "Descriptions": [
                  {
                     "FeedSource": "dde58b3b-145b-4864-9f7c-43c64c2fe815",
                     "Value": "Football"
                  },
                  {
                     "FeedSource": "e4b9ad44-00d7-4216-adf5-3a37eafc4c93",
                     "Value": "Football"
                  }
               ],
               "Synonyms": [
                  "Football"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how a query is written to pull back this document by searching for the synonym **"Football"**. Looks like it should be easy!

I got this approach after reading this: http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/elasticsearch-five-things-i-was-doing-wrong/ 
He mentions storing multiple fields in arrays. I realise my example does not have multiple fields, but we will certainly be looking for a solution which can cater for them.

Tried various different queries with filters, bool things, term this and terms that, none return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your search and mappings look like?

If you let Elasticsearch generate the mapping, it'll use the standard analyzer which lowercases the text (and removes stopwords).

So `Football` will actually be indexed as `football`. The `term`-family of queries/filters do not do text analysis, so `term:Football` will be looking for `Football`, which is not indexed.  The `match`-family of queries do.

This is a very common problem, and is covered quite extensively in my article on [Troubleshooting Elasticsearch searches, for Beginners](https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/), which can be worth skimming through. Text analysis is a very important part of working with search, so there's [some more articles about](https://www.found.no/tag/analyzers/) it as well.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply (and Akshay). I will certainly look through the beginners guide. A few days and it'll all start sinking in...

Answer (score 2):

A simple match query would work in this scenario.

```
POST integration-test-static/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "Synonyms": "Football"
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
   "took": 0,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.30685282,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "integration-test-static",
            "_type": "sport",
            "_id": "4d38e07b-f3d3-4af2-9221-60450b18264a",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "Descriptions": [
                  {
                     "FeedSource": "dde58b3b-145b-4864-9f7c-43c64c2fe815",
                     "Value": "Football"
                  },
                  {
                     "FeedSource": "e4b9ad44-00d7-4216-adf5-3a37eafc4c93",
                     "Value": "Football"
                  }
               ],
               "Synonyms": [
                  "Football"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also confirm that this works. Could you possibly show how I might find "Football" only. To avoid returning "American Football" for example?

Comment: As Alex says, there's a lot you can do with analyzers to help you with your indexing and queries. A simple one to look at is the "keyword" analyzer. That will convert everything to lower case, but treat the entire string as a single word and not split it up. So a search for the term:football will not match term:"american football"

Comment: The keyword analyzer was exactly what I was looking for here.